# How to create pulsing circle animation during drag and drop in android

Tags: android, animation, drawable

[image: example animation]something like [Pulsing animation in iOS](https://github.com/shu223/PulsingHalo)
Please help

**EDIT** I'm using [Ripple animation library](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background) suggested by Alexander. I want this animation during drag and drop as well please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [Android Ripple Background](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background) library.

Comment: Actually, I want this animation during drag and drop. I noticed that during drag and drop this animation is not working

Comment: I need the same thing, but for the website, not for android. can someone explain how to do?

Comment: @MileMijatovic, not me. I'm an Android developer

Comment: @Alexander: I need to do similar thing on a map marker, any idea how I can achieve that ? Thanks